# collection_check_boxes in nested forms won't insert into join table correctly with many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have nested forms that are attempting to make an insert into the `Categorization` model for each check box. As a result, I am getting no errors but one of the attributes of the `Categorization` model is not getting inserted into the table. This is what the hash looks like with 2 out of 3 checkboxes checked :`"categorizations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"clothing_size_id"=>["1", "2", ""]}}}`

The insert looks like this: `SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "categorizations" ("created_at", "product_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 23 Jun 2014 17:44:45 UTC +00:00], ["product_id", 15], ["updated_at", Mon, 23 Jun 2014 17:44:45 UTC +00:00]]`

The insert needs to be constructed with a `"clothing_size_id"` as well like this I think `("created_at", "product_id", "updated_at", "clothing_size_id")`

How do I get this to insert correctly?

The clothing sizes from the `ClothingSize` model are being displayed with check boxes on the `Product` form. Each check box is supposed to make 1 row in the `Categorization` model with the same `product_id` and the `clothing_size_id` of each check box checked.

Models

Product

```
has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :clothing_sizes, through: :categorizations

accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :clothing_sizes
```

Categorization

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :clothing_size

accepts_nested_attributes_for :clothing_size
```

ClothingSize

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :products, through: :categorizations

accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
```

Products Controller

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.categorizations.build
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, 
    :image_url, :image_url2, :price, :quantity, :color, 
    :clothing_sizes_attributes => [:sizes, :clothing_size_id],
    :categorizations_attributes => {:clothing_size_id => []})
end
```

_form for Products

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :categorizations do |cat| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= cat.collection_check_boxes :clothing_size_id, ClothingSize.all, :id, :sizes, {prompt: "Size"}  %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save Product'%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What happens if you change all instances of `clothing_size_id` to the plural, `clothing_size_ids`?

Comment: Hey Joe. I get `undefined method 'clothing_size_ids' for #<Categorization:0x007fb7f00a0370>` when I make it plural in the view. I get `Unpermitted parameters: clothing_size_id
` when I make it plural in the `Products` controller in the `def product_params method`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to take your clothing size ids out of categorizations.

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :clothing_size_ids, ClothingSize.all, :id, :sizes { prompt: "Size" } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then in your controller:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, 
         :image_url, :image_url2, :price, :quantity, :color, 
         { clothing_size_ids: [] })
end
```

And finally, I don't think you need to accept nested attribute for either association in your product model.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :clothing_sizes, through: :categorizations

  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :clothing_sizes
end
```

end

Try that out, and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: That works. So I guess don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on any of the models for this situation because `clothing_size_id` is part of the `Categorization` model and there are not other attributes getting saved that aren't on the `Product` model?

Comment: I believe you're correct, you shouldn't need them. You'll generally never really need nested attributes for a join model (aka your `Categorization` model), and the only reason you'd need nested attributes for `ClothingSize` would be if you were actually creating clothing sizes with every product. Since in this case it seems like you're creating clothing sizes separately, you won't need nested attributes.

Comment: I see. Thanks again. Looks like I made it more complicated than it is.

Comment: No problem! And it happens. That's what SO is for. I'd also suggest taking a look through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) if you haven't already. They're incredibly helpful, and I basically every time I refer back to them I learn something new.

Comment: @JoeKennedy Thank you so much for your answer, this is so much simpler than other SO answers provide but I was really struggling with this!